# useEffect cleanup function does not immediately update data?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

How/When does the cleanup function update data?

I am clearing the state in cleanup fn but it does not reflecting the changed data.

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const data = useSelector((state) => state.staticPageReducer)
```

This is the useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data)
        if (!data.isFetched) dispatch(fetchStaticPage(pageType))

        return () => {
          dispatch(clearStaticPage())
        }
    }, [])
```

This is the reducer

```
import { StaticPageActions } from "./actions"

const defaultState = {
    data: {},
    isFetching: false,
    isFetched: false,
    error: null,
}

const staticPageReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case StaticPageActions.FETCH_STATIC_PAGE_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true,
                isFetched: false,
            }

        case StaticPageActions.FETCH_STATIC_PAGE_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload.data,
                isFetching: false,
                isFetched: true,
            }

        case StaticPageActions.FETCH_STATIC_PAGE_ERROR:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                isFetched: false,
                error: action.error,
            }

        case StaticPageActions.CLEAR_STATIC_PAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetched: false,
                isFetching: false,
                data: {},
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default staticPageReducer
```

```
export const clearStaticPage = () => {
    return {
        type: StaticPageActions.CLEAR_STATIC_PAGE,
    }
}
```

Now the problem is when the cleanup function runs and after that console.log(data) still prints the previous value, but i was hoping that after clearStaticPage(), the data value will be cleared!

It would be great if anyone can clear my doubt here.

Answer (score 1):

The way your useEffect function is set up could be the source of the problem. When you have an empty array at the end of it, your component will only render on initialization, and the props/state inside the effect will always have their initial values (hence why your data variable is logging the same thing) - if you want it to update every time a variable changes, you can put it into that list (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

In your case, the useEffect function would look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data)
        if (!data.isFetched) dispatch(fetchStaticPage(pageType))

        return () => {
          dispatch(clearStaticPage())
        }
    }, [data])
```

Comment: Since cleanup is called on every re-render, this would cause an infinite loop and this useEffect will keep on running since the data will keep on changing, so data cannot be passed as a dependency. For tackling this, we can cleanup in another useEffect but that's a totally different question. My concern here is why the clearStaticPage() inside the cleanup is not immediately updating the value of data? Because console.log(data) => will be printed after cleanup and according to my understanding, it should have cleared the data, but data is same as previous

Comment: Even if I pass the data in another useeffect, i cannot see the updated data in the log

Comment: I have updated the question with the required details

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not that familiar with states in the way that you're using them. From what I do understand it looks like you're not actually updating your state, but just copying your defaultState then overwriting the copy in your reducer's return statements. To actually update your state you would need to define a state somewhere and then call setState to actually change that state. Does what I described happen anywhere?